# Get field name of JSON

Tags: php, json

i have a JSON with list of servers:

```
 {
    "serverlist": {
        "live": {
            "Echo server": {
                "age": "00:05:39",
                "title": "sometitle"
            },
            "Rio server": {
                "age": "00:02:57",
                "title": "sometitle"
            },
            "Goodies server": {
                "age": "00:04:14",
                "title": "sometitle"
            },
            "Ben server": {
                "age": "00:03:30",
                "title": "sometitle"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i have this code:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("jsonurl");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
$parsed_json = $parsed_json['serverlist']['live'];

foreach($parsed_json as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value['age'] . '<br>';
   echo $value['tist'] . '<br>';
}
```

im trying to get the each server name (echo server, rio server etc).
how can i do that?

Comment: It's `$key` isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server names are the keys, so it would be in the `$key` variable.

```
foreach($parsed_json as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key . '<br>';
   echo $value['age'] . '<br>';
   echo $value['tist'] . '<br>';
}
```